# print element of an array by assigning to variables

Tags: perl

I am unable to print array element values as expected. `@array = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);`

I want to assign first value to variable a and second to variable b

```
for (my $index = 0; $index <= $# array; $index++) {
    my $a = @array[$index];
    my $b = @array[$index + 1];
    DEBUG("DEBUG:: $a and $b");
}
```

I want output like

```
    a=1 and b=2
    a=3 and b=4
    a=5 and b=6
```

Comment: `for (my $index = 0; $index <= $# array; $index++)` is along way of writing `for my $index (0..$#array)`

Comment: Avoid using `$a` and `$b` since using they can conflict with `sort` and other functions with callbacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);

my %hash = @array;

while (my ($key,$value) = each %hash) {
    print "Key is $key, Value is $value\n";
}
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/eCjmAn)

Another way

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my @array = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);
for (my $count=0; $count<@array; $count+=2){
    print "A is $array[$count], B is $array[$count+1]\n";
}
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/xfXePf)

Your way

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my @array = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);
for ( my $index=0;$index<=$#array;$index+=2)   {
    my $a1 = @array[$index];
    my $b1 = @array[$index+1]; 
    print "A is $a1, B is $b1\n";
}
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/Am7L3t)

Comment: Thanks you are a star

Comment: The first option will print them in pairs but they might not be in order

Comment: Yes, as it's in hash. I'm not sure if OP needs ordered output. I'll edit if he confirms.

Answer (score 1):

The root cause for your issue is you should use '$index+=2' instead of '$index++' to incress $index.

Answer (score 0):

When i understand your problem right, you want to have a loop, incrementing by 2:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
my @array = (1, 2, 3,4,5,6,7,8);
my (@array_a, @array_b);
for (my $count=0; $count < $#array; $count+=2) {
  say "a is $array[$count], b is $array[$count+1]";
}
```

Output:

```
a is 1, b is 2
a is 3, b is 4
a is 5, b is 6
a is 7, b is 8
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the modulus operator:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my @array = (1 .. 8);

foreach (@array){
    $_ % 2 == 0 ? print "b = $_\n" : print "a = $_\t";
}
```

--

```
a = 1   b = 2
a = 3   b = 4
a = 5   b = 6
a = 7   b = 8
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted by others, the simple fix is to change your loop incrementor to `+= 2`. An alternative approach is to use [`splice`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html):

```
my @array = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);

while (my ($x, $y) = splice @array, 0, 2) {
    DEBUG("DEBUG:: $x and $y");
}
```

This removes the items from `@array` so you may need to make a copy first.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple approach that hasn't been mentioned yet:

```
while (@array) {
    my $x = shift(@array);
    my $y = shift(@array);
    DEBUG("DEBUG:: $x and $y");
}
```

However, it has the side-effect of emptying `@array`.